# MembershipProvider - Cookie or Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What does MembershipProvider class in ASP.NET use to authenticate users on the HTTP level? Is it Cookie or Session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Cookies.

#### Long answer:

Neither. The `MembershipProvider` class itself does not concern itself with HTTP session state. `MembershipProvider` is an abstract base class whose child classes define different ways to manage users, their passwords, etc.

However, ASP.NET uses the `FormsAuthentication` class by default to [set a difficult-to-guess authentication cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) when the user gets logged in (after authenticating with `MembershipUtil`. This in turn allows ASP.NET to populate the `HttpContext.Current.User` property during each request.

Comment: do you have link for my reference?

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo: Turns out I wasn't quite right. See my updated answer.